# GAE development server memcached never returns anything

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached, local

I have some simple python code running in Google App Engine such as this:

```
types = memcache.get('types')
if types is None:
    # do something, creating a 'types' object
    memcache.set('types', types, 36000000)
```

Whenever I run this on the local development server, `memcache.get('types')` always returns None. It is not the same live on App Engine, the memcache calls work correctly.

Is it necessary to install a separate package along with the GAE development server locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `time` argument to `memcache.set` can be a maximum of one month to indicate a relative lifetime, otherwise it is interpreted as an  absolute unix timestamp (seconds since 1970). 36000000 is much more than a month and so it's setting the entry to expire in February 1971.

If you want something to stay in cache for as long as possible, then leave out the time argument.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested and it seems you're right. Just out of curiosity, where do the docs express this one month limitation? I can't find it.

Comment: Nevermind, found it: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_set